# My variable in Controller is not loaded to blade

Tags: php, laravel

## Question

Why my variable in `ProfileController` is not loaded in my blade(`index2.blade.php`)?

## Error Message

`Undefined variable: plus (View: /work/resources/views/stories/index2.blade.php)`

## My Codes

`routes/web.php`

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('login'); 

Route::match(['get','post','middleweare'=>'auth'], '/', 
    'StoriesController@index',
    'StoriesController@store',
    'ProfileController@index',
    'ProfileController@store'
);

Route::match(['get','post','middleweare'=>'auth'], 'stories/create',
    'StoriesController@add',
    'StoriesController@upload'
);

Route::match(['get','post','middleweare'=>'auth'], 'profile/create',
    'ProfileController@add',
    'ProfileController@upload'
);

Route::group(['middleweare' => 'auth','name'=>'profile'], function () {
    Route::get('/profile/edit', 'ProfileController@edit');
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();
```

`app/Http/Controllers/ProfileController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\stories;
use App\History;
use App\Posts;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Storage;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request) 
    {

      $plus = Posts::all();

      return view('stories.index2', compact('plus'));
    }

    public function upload(Request $request)
      {
        $this->validate($request, [
          'file' => [
           
            'required',
            'file',
            'image',
            'mimes:jpeg,png',
          ]
        ]);
  
        if ($request->file('file')->isValid([])) {
          $path = $request->file->store('public');
          return view('stories.index2')->with('filename', basename($path));
        } else {
          return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors();
        }
    }
    
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

      $d = new \DateTime();
      $d->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo'));
      $dir = $d->format('Y/m');
      $path = sprintf('public/posts/%s', $dir);

      
      $data = $request->except('_token');

      foreach ($data['plus'] as $k => $v) {

        $filename = '';

        
        $posts = Posts::take(1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
          
          $filename = $post->id + 1 . '_' . $v->getClientOriginalName();
        }
        unset($post);

       
        if ($filename == false) {
          $filename = 1 . '_' . $v->getClientOriginalName();
        }

        
        $v->storeAs($path, $filename);

        $post_data = [
          'path' => sprintf('posts/%s/', $dir),
          'name' => $filename
        ];
        $a = new Posts();
        $a->fill($post_data)->save();
      }

      unset($k, $v);

      return redirect('/');
    }

    
    public function create(Request $request)
      {
        $this->validate($request, Profile::$rules);
  
        $profile = new Profile;
        $form = $request->all();
  
  
        unset($form['_token']);
  
        $profile->fill($form);
        $profile->save();
  
        return redirect('/');
      }

    public function add()
      {
        return view('profile.create2');
      }
      
    public function edit()
      {
        return view('profile.edit');
      }
      




    
}
```

`resources/views/stories/index2.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.front2')
@section('title','mainpage')

@section('content')
<div class="profile">

    <div class="profileimg">
        @foreach ($plus as $pplus)
        <img src="/storage/{{ $pplus->path . $pplus->name }}" style="height: 210px; width: 210px; border-radius: 50%;">
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="name">
        @guest
        <a class="nav-link2" href="{{ route('register')}}">{{ __('Create Accout!')}}</a>
        @else
        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link2" href="#" role="button">
            {{Auth::user()->name}}<span class="caret"></span></a>



        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            @csrf
        </form>
    </div>
    @endguest


    <div class="aboutme">
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
    </div>

</div>

<div class="new">

    <div class="newtitle">
        <h1>New</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container1">

        @foreach ($plus as $pplus)
        <img src="/storage/{{ $pplus->path . $pplus->name }}" class="images" style="height: 150px; width: 150px; border-radius: 50%;">
        @endforeach
        <div class="more">
            more...
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="stories">

    <div class="titlestories">
        <h1>Stories</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">

        <div class="titleclose">
            <h2>#CloseFriends</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="titlefollow">
            <h2>#Follows</h2>
        </div>

        

      
    </div>
</div>

{{ csrf_field() }}
@endsection
```

Comment: Can you show the `index2.blade.php` file? It seems the error is there.

Comment: did you try the solution i posted below ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your upload method, you're missing the `$plus` variable

Change it to this

```php
public function upload(Request $request)
      {
        $this->validate($request, [
          'file' => [

            'required',
            'file',
            'image',
            'mimes:jpeg,png',
          ]
        ]);

        if ($request->file('file')->isValid([])) {
          $path = $request->file->store('public');
          $filename = basename($path);
          $plus = Posts::all();
          return view('stories.index2', compact('filename','plus'));
        } else {
          return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for answering I tried that code, but nothing has been changed...

Answer (score -1):

`return view('stories.index2, [ 'plus' => Posts::all() ]);` should work.

Comment: `return view('stories.index2', compact('plus'));` should also work

Comment: Hi! I know, but it's odd... I answered this to force passing a variable name.

Comment: Thank you for answering I tried that code, but nothing has been changed...